# Dev-C++: Why isn't curses.h included?

Tags: c, ide, include

I've installed Orwell Dev-C++ 5.x and the PDCurses DevPak. However, when I try to compile the example curses application, the compiler/linker complains that it can't find `curses.h`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before reading any further, keep in mind that Dev-C++ is old software, the use of which is not recommended. Rather use Code:Blocks, Visual Studio or something similar.

The issue being experienced is as a result of the project's configuration being incomplete. Make sure that the "Includes" section (Project Properties) has an entry for the directory containing `curses.h` ( `{installDir}/include`) and "Libraries" (also in "Project Properties") has an entry for `{installDir}/libs`, which contains `curses.a`.

Ideally, these directories should be set as part of the IDE configuration rather than at the project level. The process of doing so is similar to that described above.

Note that you will have to add the appropriate directories for the curses library and header to a custom makefile (`-I` for includes and `-L` for libraries) as part of the project. (Adding it to the auto-generated makefile will not work.) To do this:

1. Save a copy of the makefile (`Makefile.win`) made on first compilation (which failed) as `Makefile.curses`.
2. Edit the makefile to contain the appropriate directives (`-I{installDir}/include` after the other includes and `-L{installDir}/libs` after the other libraries).
3. In the project's configuration/build options, check 'Use Custom Makefile' and set it to `Makefile.curses`.